# How to trasform a Json list to a key-value object

Tags: json, key-value, jolt

I have a Json with this structure:

```
{"code":"0000",
 "usercode":"sample",
 "specifications":{ 
    "c":"d","e":"f"
}}
```

I need to build a jolt to convert the json to this form:

```
{"code":"0000",
 "usercode":"sample",
 "specifications":[
      {"key":"c",
       "value":"d"},
      {"key":"e",
       "value":"f"}
]}
```

I tried this, but is my first jolt.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "code": "code",
      "usercode": "usercode",
      "specifications": {
        "*": {
          "key": "@c",
          "value": "@d"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check this example: https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#mapToList to understand whats going on :)

This spec will do the trick:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "code": "&",
      "usercode": "&",
      "specifications": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2[#2].key",
          "@": "&2[#2].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```